# Is there a way to keep the Xcode console log from overflowing and locking up the session?

Tags: xcode

I have a Mac app (that is a testbed for a phone app) that spews massive amounts of output into the console log.  Mostly this is what I want, but sometimes I run large "batch" runs and the console log essentially fills up and Xcode locks up.  The only way I've found to prevent this is to monitor the job and every 30 seconds or so press "Clear", hoping that I'm not so close to the end that I clear out the 50 or so final lines giving the results of the run.

Yes, I could go through the code and reduce the number of lines output, but there are several reasons (not purely based on laziness) for not doing that.

Does anyone know of a way to tell Xcode to maintain the console as a "rotating buffer" of sorts, clearing old stuff from time to time so that it doesn't fill up?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own rotating buffer implementation, and log to that rather than with printf.

Or if you don't want to replace all your printfs:

```
 #define printf rotatingPrintf
```

Perhaps it would work to write a command-line tool that has a rotating buffer, then pipe the output of your app to that tool.  You can launch GUI apps from the command line like this:

```
 $ /Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
```